# There is an error when I try export my r-markdown to pdf

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, export-to-pdf

So I need to do an activity for my class, and it includes a set of data from excel, and then export it to pdf. Even though I already imported the data from excel to the program, and attached it to the Rmarkdown, and additionally the program runs perfectly. When I tried to knit it to pdf it doesn't work, and it says I have this error:

```
Error in attach(encuesta) : object 'encuesta' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> 
eval -> attach
Execution halted
```

I have searched so many internet pages looking for a solution and none works! Please help me!! I know that using attach() it's not advised, however when I try to use another one (for example:

```
{r setup, include=FALSE}
library("readxl")
encuesta <- read.table(file.choose(), header = TRUE,fill = TRUE)
encuesta
```

)Another problem arises. Any solutions??? And sorry in advance because I am veryyy new at R.

Comment: Part of the problem might be trying to use `file.choose()`. You can't do anything interactively when when rendering to pdf like that. Make sure to put the path to your data file in the code so it can run without human intervention. Possibly make it a parameter do your document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. I am guessing your Excel file is called "encuesta.xlsx".  Put that Excel file in the same folder as your .rmd file and give this a try.

````
```{r loadExcel}
library(readxl)
encuesta <- read_excel("encuesta.xlsx") 
encuesta
```
````

If you can, try to use RStudio to knit to a PDF.  Use the downward pointing triangle next to the knit button (just above where you typed your .rmd code) and choose "Knit to PDF".

Comment: @SofíaVesga.  Glad it helped. Please click the green check mark next to my answer.  That marks it as an acceptable solution.